# Problem parsing XML output using community XML module in Ansible

Tags: xml, ansible, firewall

I have a string of output from a query I have ran against a firewall. When I try to parse the string using the community XML module, I am getting an output of:

> fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error while parsing document: xml_string (Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1))"}

From:

```
    - name: Gather allocated number of addresses for LAN interface...
      community.general.xml:
        xmlstring: ethernet1-1_output.content
        xpath: "/x:response/x:result/x:interface[@name='allocated']"
      register: allocated_ethernet1-1
```

I have debugged my input and it does seem to be valid XML according to VS.Code. But there are extra characters I think Ansible is adding that might be giving it a problem.

```
<response status=\"success\">
    <result>
        <interface name=\"ethernet1/1\" id=\"258\" allocated=\"40\" total=\"150\">
            <entry name=\"10.10.10.10\">\n
```

Is there a way to get a more 'unmodified' output from an API query? Or an easier way to format this to be more module-readable? The goal is to grab the allocated and total values as separate numbers.

Comment: The xml file must start with an angle bracket with no whitespaces before the angle bracket.  You probably have spaces before the angle bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you simply forgot to surround your variable name with curly braces, so Ansible interprets `ethernet1-1_output.content` as a string. You should use Jinja2 templating instead to [reference a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-simple-variables):

```yaml
    - name: Gather allocated number of addresses for LAN interface...
      community.general.xml:
        xmlstring: "{{ ethernet1-1_output.content }}"
        xpath: "/x:response/x:result/x:interface[@name='allocated']"
      register: allocated_ethernet1-1
```

> But there are extra characters I think Ansible is adding that might be giving it a problem.

> Is there a way to get a more 'unmodified' output from an API query? Or an easier way to format this to be more module-readable?

Ansible does not add any extra characters. The output you've posted is probably copied from a `debug` task console output, isn't it? By default, Ansible outputs the task execution results as JSON, so any double quotes or control characters should be escaped. To have more human-readable console output, you can use [`community.general.yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-yaml-callback) stdout callback or setting [`callback_result_format = yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html#parameter-result_format) for the default callback (note that these two options are not equal):

```ini
; ansible.cfg

[defaults]
callback_result_format = yaml
stdout_callback = community.general.yaml
```

Using these, Ansible will log the variables "as is" to console.
Note that is **does not affect** the way how the variable values are interpreted internally.

Comment: OK, that was the right call. It was not recognizing it as a variable as you mentioned. 

New problem with the XML parser, but I am going to open a new thread after I see if I can figure it out on my own.